# JAVA Import failed

Tags: java, apache, classpath

I am facing a very strange type of java classpath problem. I have added path d:\javaext in the java classpath environment variable and when enter on the command prompt `echo %classpath%` , it shows the said path in the printed list but even then, when I try to compile a java file in which I am importing the package by adding `import org.apache.commons.lang.*;`, it some how says that the said package doesn't exist. The relevant jar file physically exists on that path also. Any clue that what am I missing, although it's a very basic stuff. I have also tried compiling it with setting the classpath on runtime by `javac -cp` or `javac -classpath` switch but even then no success.

I am trying to compile the code with java 1.8 on windows 8.1

Can Anybody tell that what this alert means in the property dialog box of the jar file?

[image: Properties Dialog Box of the jar file]

Comment: is your apache commons library exists in the location "d:\javaext" ?

Comment: @vembutech Yes, it is.

Comment: Why aren't you using ANT, Maven, or an IDE?

Comment: @EJP I don't know much about creating a java project with Maven or ANT

Answer (score 0):

Your .Jar file might be corrupt.
Else on Windows try to set path through Environment Variable.
And on Linux , export the path for temporary usage or set in bashrc or bash profile.....

Comment: I am facing this problem on Window 8.1 and using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by differences between version of a certain "jar", some third-party libraries does not support backward compatibility. So, try browsing through the "jar" to find the package-class combination that you are using.

Hope this helps, 
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume that the are no spaces inside the path, e.g. "C:\Program Files"? If there are spaces, try surrounding the classpath variable with quotes.